# How to write a float number to a string, exactly how it is stored in a variable?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have a variable that stores a float number. I don't know its precision after floating point. And I need to write it to a string.
To do this with sprintf(), I need to know the accuracy.

```
float a = 3.45; // may change (3.456 , 3.4567 , 3.4 ...)
char result[10];
sprintf(result, "%f", a); // 
printf("%s", result); // result = "3.450000" but i need "3.45"
```

Help! How can I find out the precision of a number stored in a variable? Or tell me another way how to write a float to a string?

Comment: `sprintf(result, "%.2f", a);`?

Comment: Use `"%.50f"` to find out what your real number is.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wrote that another number can be stored in the variable, for example 3.456 and then "%.2f" will not work, you will need to enter "%.3f" and so on. I need strlen for float))))

Comment: Given the way floating point numbers are stored (in approximations based on a sign, exponent of two, and mantissa), you won't likely be able to dynamically determine the precision of your literal assignment.  Have you considered using a fixed-point decimal representation?

Comment: Consider a car's speedometer. It indicates speed to the nearest 1kph (or mph)... The speedometer may register 80kph, but the vehicle may be travelling 79.7458748kph... You format your output to "practical" precision, not based on how many digits there may be beyond your 'cut-off'... "3.46" is probably close enough to the "3.456" example.

Comment: About the "other way", have you considered the `g` format specifier? See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/aebr47s9x .

Comment: What is you actual assignment or exercise? What are its requirements? What are its limitations? What you ask for is not really possible, but if we know what your actual and original problem, exercise or assignment is, then we understand better how to help you within the limits of what's possible.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
I need to declare my float type and make a converter for it. my type is a structure of two arrays[32]. in the first one I want to store the value of the number , and in the second scale where the exponent is stored. For example 3.45 (ar1[32] = 345, ar2[32] = 2)

Comment: @AndreyRomashev: If you have your own format, then you have your own information about the digits in the number. So what prevents you from converting the number? If the significand is 345 and the scale is 2, meaning to multiply the significand by 10^−2, then you know there are two digits after the decimal point. This would have nothing to do with using `printf` to convert a `float`. You would simply print the integer part of the number, then a “.”, then the digits after the decimal point, all of which can be computed with integer arithmetic. Edit the question to clarify the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values are commonly stored as **binary** values, but we humans love to read them **decimal**. Unfortunately there is rarely an exact mapping of the fractional part ("after floating point").

To learn more, please read for example [this Wikipedia page about floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic).

For example, decimal 0.1 cannot be expressed in binary within limited space, since its expansion does not terminate. 0.1 = 1/10 = 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/256 + ... Cited from said Wikipedia page:

> Whether or not a rational number has a terminating expansion depends on the base. For example, in base-10 the number 1/2 has a terminating expansion (0.5) while the number 1/3 does not (0.333...). In base-2 only rationals with denominators that are powers of 2 (such as 1/2 or 3/16) are terminating.

Bottom line: You cannot know the number of digits after the decimal point. Instead limit the number to a reasonable value, which depends on the value's size and your requirements.

Comment: eh, I thought maybe there is some way) okay) thanks for the answer